# different textures in android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

i want to make more than one texture on a cube as easy as possible. there should be a different texture (picture like the one loaded in the loadtexture method, android.png) on each side of the cube. part of my code:

```
public class Square2 {

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;   // buffer holding the vertices
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer2;  // buffer holding the vertices
[and so on for all 6 sides]
private float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f,       // V1 - bottom left
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f,       // V2 - top left
         1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f,       // V3 - bottom right
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f         // V4 - top right
};
private float vertices2[] = {
        1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f,        // V1 - bottom left
        1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f,        // V2 - top left
        1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f,        // V3 - bottom right
        1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f         // V4 - top right
};
[for all 6 sides too]

private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
private FloatBuffer textureBuffer2; // buffer holding the texture coordinates
[and so on for all 6 sides]

private float texture[] = {         
        // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
        0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
        0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
        1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
        1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
};

private float texture2[] = {            
        // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
        0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
        0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
        1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
        1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
};

[dont really understand the texture array, is one enough for all sides, even if i want different textures?]

/** The texture pointer */
private int[] textures = new int[6];

public Square2() {
    // a float has 4 bytes so we allocate for each coordinate 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // allocates the memory from the byte buffer
    vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

    // fill the vertexBuffer with the vertices
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);

    // set the cursor position to the beginning of the buffer
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices2.length * 4);
    byteBuffer2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // allocates the memory from the byte buffer
    vertexBuffer2 = byteBuffer2.asFloatBuffer();

    // fill the vertexBuffer with the vertices
    vertexBuffer2.put(vertices2);

    // set the cursor position to the beginning of the buffer
    vertexBuffer2.position(0);


    [and so on for all 6 sides]


    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);

    [and so on]
}

/**
 * Load the texture for the square
 * @param gl
 * @param context
 */
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    // loading texture
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.android);

    // generate one texture pointer
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

    // ...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // create nearest filtered texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
            //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
            //gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Clean up
    bitmap.recycle();
}

/** The draw method for the square with the GL context */
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // bind the previously generated texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);

    // Point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    // Point to our vertex buffer1 vorn
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    //2 rechts
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer2);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer2);

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices2.length / 3);

    [and so on]

    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
}
```

unfortunately this just gives me the same texture on all sides. how can i make different textures on each side? do i have to call the loadtexture method more than one time or edit it? thought about not recycling the bitmap, would that help?

Comment: You might want to edit your question with more details. What *exactly* are you trying to achieve here? Different textures on each side of the cube? Multitexturing?

Comment: thanks, just did that :) hope it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

Thera are may ways to achieve this. The most straight forward would be to load all the textures, then bind a different one before each side is drawn (so all you are missing is `glBindTexture` before each `glDrawArrays`). For this case you do not need multiple texture coordinate buffers and overall you wouldn't even need multiple vertex buffers. You can create 1 square buffer and position (rotate) it with matrices for each side (+ binding the correct texture).

Another approach is to use a single texture to which you can load all 6 images via `glTextureSubImage` (all being at different parts of the texture, no overlapping) and then use different texture coordinates for each side of the cube. By doing this you can create a single vertex/texture buffer for the whole cube and are able to draw it with a single `glDrawArrays` call. Though in your specific case that would be no less then 4x6=24 vertices.

As you said you do not understand texture coordinate arrays.. Texture coordinates are coordinates corresponding to the relative position on the texture. That being, (0,0) is the top left part of the texture(image) and (1,1) is the bottom right part of it. If the texture had 4 images on it as in 2x2 and you would for example want to use the bottom left one, your texture coordinates would look like this:

```
private float texture[] = {         
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, .5f,
        .5f, 1.0f,
        .5f, 0.5f
};
```

As for the coordinate values being larger then 1.0 or smaller then .0 I believe they can be used ether to clamp some part of the object or to repeat the texture (those 2 are bought possible parameters for texture, usually set when loading the texture). As for the number of texture coordinates it should be at least as many as the last parameter in `glDrawArrays` or as many as is the largest index+1 when using `glDrawElements`. So for your specific case you can have only 1 texture coordinate buffer unless you will at some point change your mind and want one of the sides to have rotated image on it and solve that by changing texture coordinates.